# AWS Glue Test Connection to MySQL RDS Instance Failing with no error in log

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I'm trying to add a connection in AWS Glue to my MySQL RDS instance. I want everything encrypted as far as possible so I've followed the [instructions in the developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/set-up-encryption.html):

- IAM Roles/Policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "[arn to aws/glue key]"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
            "Resource": "[arn to CMK for encrypting RDS DB password]"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "[arn to aws/S3 key]"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "[arn to CMK for encrypting data catalog, job bookmarks, etc.]"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:AssociateKmsKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "[arn to all log groups relating to the attached IAM role]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- KMS key policy for [arn to CMK for encrypting data catalog, job bookmarks, etc.] (includes the following among other statements).

```
{
            "Sid": "EncryptedCloudWatchLogs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt*",
                "kms:Decrypt*",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "[arn to CMK for encrypting data catalog, job bookmarks, etc.]"
        }
```

- DNS Setup
  [VPC DNS Settings Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJh5V.png)
- [Self Referencing Rule in RDS Database Security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODRiR.png)

  When I test the connection, it fails. This is literally the *only* line in the CloudWatch log when I test the connection:

```
2019-12-28 15:37:53 INFO  CatalogClient:682 - Got connection 'Foo' info from Catalog with url: jdbc:mysql://[RDS ENDPOINT]:3306/[DBNAME]
```

I've followed the troubleshooting tips [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-test-connection-failed/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/troubleshooting-connection.html) several times. Namely:

- I've used MySQL workbench to connect to my RDS instance using the exact same username and password. This user has admin level permissions. The JDBC URL from the Glue Connection is the same I use in my Workbench connection.
- I've got more than 100 free IP addresses in my RDS instance's subnet
- I've confirmed the attachement of an IAM role that includes the AWS managed "AWSGlueServiceRole" policy
- I've launched a separate EC2 instance within the same subnet and security group and connected successfully to the RDS instance through SSH.
- "Require SSL Connection" has been selected on the Connection configuration. However, I've tested this with and without this option selected and it won't connect either way.
- MySQL version is 5.6.35

  Everything seems to check out fine. What am I missing?

Comment: not enough information.  try to provide some additional info screenshot, detailed errorlog, and also did you ensure if the RDS is running?  Also i will check if the credentials are correct, and if am able to connect to RDS from an mysql client.

Comment: Updated post to provide many more details.